# How to replace spaces with _ for specific lines

Tags: sed, replace

I have a text file with multiple paragraphs. Each paragraph has headers with spaces. I want to replace the spaces of the text found between `[` and `:`, with `_` .
Here is an excerpt of the text from the file I am talking about

```
[Candidatus Protochlamydia amoebophila UWE25: NC_005861]
MNQRTGILLVNLGTPKTPRPKDVYRYLNEFLTDGRVIDLPWLKRQLLVRC
IIVPFRYKQSSMLYQKLWTAEGSPLLVHGIAVQTKLQMILGESFQVELAM


[Gluconobacter oxydans 621H: NC_006677]
MAFLHKTPRIAPPPEGRTGILLINLGTPDDTGYFSVRRYLSEFLSDRRVI
ESPPLIWQPILQSIILTKRPFASGANYARIWHKEENASPLRVYTRRQAEG
```

I need it to be changed into this:

```
[Candidatus_Protochlamydia_amoebophila_UWE25: NC_005861]
MNQRTGILLVNLGTPKTPRPKDVYRYLNEFLTDGRVIDLPWLKRQLLVRC
IIVPFRYKQSSMLYQKLWTAEGSPLLVHGIAVQTKLQMILGESFQVELAM


[Gluconobacter_oxydans_621H: NC_006677]
MAFLHKTPRIAPPPEGRTGILLINLGTPDDTGYFSVRRYLSEFLSDRRVI
ESPPLIWQPILQSIILTKRPFASGANYARIWHKEENASPLRVYTRRQAEG
```

I've tried

```
$ sed -e 's/\s\+/_/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

but that replaces all spaces with `_`
How can I set a limitation on this command?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a loop, replacing spaces one at a time until there are no more before the first colon:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/[^:]* [^:]*:/s/ /_/;ta' input.txt 
[Candidatus_Protochlamydia_amoebophila_UWE25: NC_005861]
MNQRTGILLVNLGTPKTPRPKDVYRYLNEFLTDGRVIDLPWLKRQLLVRC
IIVPFRYKQSSMLYQKLWTAEGSPLLVHGIAVQTKLQMILGESFQVELAM


[Gluconobacter_oxydans_621H: NC_006677]
MAFLHKTPRIAPPPEGRTGILLINLGTPDDTGYFSVRRYLSEFLSDRRVI
ESPPLIWQPILQSIILTKRPFASGANYARIWHKEENASPLRVYTRRQAEG
```

A more KISS approach might be to replace all spaces - and then re-replace the one after the colon:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/_/g' -e 's/:_/: /' input.txt
```

If Perl is an option, you could use *negative lookbehind* to only replace those instances that are not preceded by a colon:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!:) /_/g' input.txt
```

Comment: The first option worked great! Thank you!